# How do i Screen scrape html page generated by javascript

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

How do i screen **scrape** a html page generated by javascript?
Ive tried something like this:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("http://stats.nba.com/scores.html?gameDate=04/11/2014");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='scoreboards']");
```

This doesn't work however because the content is generated by javascript. Is there a way to scrape the page after the javascript has generated the html?
Maybe using something other then agility pack?

Comment: user webbrowser control if u want to scrap html created by javascript

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper can you give me an example or link me to one?:)

Answer (score 2):

Use a webbrowser control to get content and element witch loded by js or ajax

```
private void LoadHtmlWithBrowser(String url)
{
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

    waitTillLoad(this.webBrowser1);

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument; 
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML); 
    doc.Load(sr);
}

private void waitTillLoad(WebBrowser webBrControl)
{
    WebBrowserReadyState loadStatus;
    int waittime = 100000;
    int counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
        Application.DoEvents();
        if ((counter > waittime) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive))
        {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrControl.IsBusy != true)
        {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have some questions, Where is WebBrowser1 instansiated? And what do you mean by loaded by ajax or js?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a webbrowser object that is a c# object that acts like a browser and runs javascript code and after recieving a response parse it with the agility pack.

[MSDN - Web Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)